# "Must declare the scalar variable" for parameter (C# SqlCommand)

Tags: c#, sql, sqlcommand

```
string selectedAreas = getSelectedAreas(areaCounts);

SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "select top 1 [x1] " +
                  "from sometable " +
                  "where sometable.coll = @selectedAreas" +
                  "order by NEWID() ";
cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
cmd.Connection = cn;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@selectedAreas", selectedAreas);
```

What am I doing wrong here?

I get

> *Must declare the scalar variable for @selectedAreas.*

`@selectedAreas` might become something like:

```
" 'nyc' or sometable.coll = 'la' or sometable.coll = 'miami' "
```

Edit:

I added the space as the comment below pointed out. And removed the paramter, like this:

```
cmd.CommandText = "select top 1 [x1] " +
                  "from sometable " +
                  "where sometable.coll = " + selectedAreas
                  " order by NEWID() ";
```

Dont know how correct it is but it works for now...

Comment: You need a space after `@selectedAreas` in your SQL. As for your value, it isn't going to work.

Comment: ...stupid space. OK so how can I make it work?

Comment: Standard warning: Beware SQL injection with this approach.

Comment: For the second part of the problem, perhaps [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterizing-an-sql-in-clause) might be a starting point. For your edited approach, please find the delete button.

Answer (score 1):

It could be the way you are running the command (which you didn't include in your question), such as in this case: [Must Declare Scalar Variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10602439/must-declare-scalar-variable)